# Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined Django jQuery CDN

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I am building a Django webapp and want to use a JS extension that creates a weekly schedule [link](https://www.jqueryscript.net/time-clock/Dynamic-Weekly-Scheduler-jQuery-Schedule.html). I have placed this extension in the static directory of my project and imported jQuery and the extension in the  of my base.html as so:

```
        <!-- jquery -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" defer></script>

        <!-- jQuery schedule display (includes css and js) -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'Dynamic-Weekly-Scheduler-jQuery-Schedule/dist/jquery.schedule.css' %}">
        <script src="{% static 'Dynamic-Weekly-Scheduler-jQuery-Schedule/dist/jquery.schedule.js' %}"></script>
```

Yet, when I attempt to pass data into this plugin as so:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    console.log({{schedule_data}})
    $("schedule").jqs({{schedule_data}})
    </script>
```

I get an error in jquery.schedule.js:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
```

referring to the end of this file that is:

```
$.fn[pluginName] = function (options) {
    var ret = false;
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    var loop = this.each(function () {
      if (!$.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName)) {
        $.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName, new Plugin(this, options));
      } else if ($.isFunction(Plugin.prototype[options])) {
        ret = $.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName)[options](args);
      }
    });

    if (ret) {
      return ret;
    }

    return loop;
  };
})(jQuery, window, document);
```

What am I doing wrong? Should I not be using jQuery CDN? Note that jQuery isn't defined elsewhere in the jquery.schedule.js document. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have to watch out about using `defer` when you load the CDN. `defer` tells the browser to wait until everything else has loaded, so in your code, the `<script>` tag you have at the bottom will start running first. You should remove the `defer` tag in the jQuery CDN and instead `defer` when you load your `<script>`. That would ensure that your jQuery library is fully loaded before you run your script.